# boost::spirit use same symbol twice

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I have a grammar similar to that one:

```
 template <class ITER>
struct MessageParser
    : public boost::spirit::qi::grammar<ITER, Message(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
    MessageParser()
        : MessageParser::base_type(start_)
    {
        string_ = +(char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *char_("a-zA-Z_0-9"));
        quoted_string_ = lexeme['"' >> +(char_ - '"') >> '"'];
        signal_ %= lit("SG_")  // type is Signal
            >> string_ >> ':'; // Signal name
        message_ %= lit("BO_") // type is Message
            >> int_
            >> string_ >> ':'
            >> +signal_; // std::map<std::string, Signal> (here is my problem)
        start_ %= message_;
    }
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<ITER, Message(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> start_;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<ITER, Message(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> message_;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<ITER, Signal(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> signal_;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<ITER, std::string()> string_;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<ITER, std::string(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> quoted_string_;
};
```

The problem is, I need the name of the `Signal` to create the `Signal` object (because it has an `name` attribute) but I also want map the Signal parsed with the rule `signal_` to the name of the Signal in the messages `std::map<std::string, Signal>` map, but I don't know how to receive the name of the signal, or how to create the needed pair for `boost::spirit` so it can insert the pair into the map.
I think I have to somehow duplicate the string holding the signal name.

How can I do this?

Comment: This looks exactly like the problem [`symbols`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html) parser solves, but actually you can achieve it in multiple different ways: transformation either via rule or [`attr_cast`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/attr_cast.html), semantic action, custom parser, and possibly I forgot some other.

Comment: Could you explain your approach in more detail? I was thinking about `symbols` like a mapper which I can use to map a parsed integer to an enum type... How I can use this to get the value of the parsed name of a other rule? The other stuff you enumerated I don't know yet. But thanks for the starting point.

Comment: @NikitaKniazev I guess I tryed to transform via semantic action, but then I run into the problem, that I don't know how to get the `std::map<std::string, Signal>` container in my custom function, I only have my `Signal&` there.

Comment: I solved it with `attr_cast` and `transform_attribute`, so thanks a lot.

Comment: 1) It can map to any type, not only an enum, the example in documentation even uses `int`. 2) Do you really need a string representation? Even if you really need, you can capture string that symbol parser matched with a `raw` directive `raw[symbols[assign_mapped_value]][assign_matched_string]`. 3) You can pass it via rules [inherited attributes (arguments)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parser_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.qi.reference.parser_concepts.nonterminal.attributes)

Comment: How am I able to pass such things via rules inherited attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `attr_cast`:

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace spirit
    {
        namespace traits
        {
            template <>
            struct transform_attribute<std::pair<std::string, Signal>, Signal, boost::spirit::qi::domain>
            {
                using type = Signal&;
                using pair_t = std::pair<std::string, Signal>;
                static Signal& pre(pair_t& pair)
                {
                    return pair.second;
                }
                static void post(pair_t& pair, const Signal& sig)
                {
                    pair.first = sig.name;
                    pair.second = sig;
                }
                static void fail(pair_t& pair)
                {
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
message_ %= lit("BO_")
    >> int_
    >> string_ >> ':'
    >> int_
    >> string_
    >> +attr_cast(signal_);
```

I hope I used everything correct (no guarantee).